# Memory dump on iOS app crash

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

Is there a way to get a memory dump in case there is a crash and than load it to Xcode?
This way I could debug the crash as if the crash happened while the device was connected to debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a full memory dump upon a crash but if you run the app under the Allocations Instrument then it records the memory allocations made.  Then when it crashes you can retrospectively inspect the contents of memory used at the time of the crash if it pertains to memory that was actually allocated (because it would be recorded in the allocation history).

It might be that Corellium could help you out here as they virtualise the whole environment and so would know the entire memory contents.  It's a proprietary service, but please post back any success if you get it with such a platform.

Answer (score -2):

Understanding and analyzing ios Application crash reports:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html

Comment: This tutorial has nothing to do with memory dumps

Comment: According to your question, i just thought you want to debug offline crash and low memory report is enough for you. But if your goal is to get full memory dump, then my answer is useless. Thanx for downvote.